# What does the title "Cello Squirrel Daffodil" ("The Magicians" S05E09) mean?

Tags: title, the-magicians

Season 5, episode 9 of **The Magicians** is named  **Cello Squirrel Daffodil**. Why is this episode named as such, from what reference is this name taken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plover is entrapped within the Poison Room in the Neitherlands. He is infected by little bugs called tongue twisters. When we see him, he is spouting gibberish, and his first words (that we hear) are ... wait for it .... "Cello, Squirrel, Daffodil".

Comment: Does cello squirrel Daffodil mean something or it is only gibberish